# PHP include variable within URL?

Tags: php, url

I am trying to echo the variable `$ipss` instead of the string below where you see `"HERE"` in my URL but I don't know how to do it.

```php
<?php $url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=HERE&lang=fr&units=metric&appid=b5f11a80423d0d4dae64f1ec1a653edf"; ?>
```

I have tried this to output the value of the variable in place but it doesn't work:

```php
<?php $url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=echo $ipss&lang=fr&units=metric&appid=b5f11a80423d0d4dae64f1ec1a653edf"; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can concatenate a value into a string using the `.` concatenate operator.

```php
<?php $url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" . $ipss . "&lang=fr&units=metric&appid=b5f11a80423d0d4dae64f1ec1a653edf"; ?>
```

Comment: yes but if i want include : $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; i can't

Comment: Why not? Please clarify what you are attempting to do with more detail.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `{}` when the full string is within double quotes, this substitutes the value of the variable in place.

```php
<?php $url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={$ipss}&lang=fr&units=metric&appid=b5f11a80423d0d4dae64f1ec1a653edf"; ?>
```